# css3 @viewport problems - is it working already anywhere

Tags: css, viewport

The question is simple: Does the `@viewport` argument already work?

Wanted to try it out but it doesn't do anything ^^

If it is already working, then can some one plese tell me what I am doing wrong?!

```css
@-o-viewport {
  width: 480px;
  zoom: 1;
}

@-ms-viewport {
  width: 480px;
  zoom: 1;
}

@viewport {
  width: 480px;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Thanks already! :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Yes** it is working and this is how you can use it
>
> See Full Documentation here [@viewport](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/)

You can use it like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">
```

---

```
@viewport {
  width: 480px;
  zoom: 1.0;
}
```

[image: Zoom]

Comment: will read the docs in detail if i find the time (but not now ;) ). But Thanks already1 :)
Does that mean I have to specify the viewport information twice, but can't modify it? Wanted to use the css way to determine the viewport and drop the meta. Hmm... maybe I know more tomorrow after reading the docs :)

Comment: Yeah read more! and accept the answer if it is helpful to you! Peace!